# fire on change event if value of multiple input elements are changed in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have two file input elements. I want that the `change` event to only fire if the event occurs on both elements.

Right now the event is fired immediately if one of each gets a file

```
$(function (){
  $(".main_input, .second__input").on("change", ()=>{
     // do stuff 
  });
});
```

I tried to implement an `and` operator but don't know how to rewrite it to jQuery syntax

```
if ($(".main_input") && $(".second__input")).on("change", ())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The change event does not hang around. You will need to count

```js
$(function () {
      const events = []
      $(".main_input, .second_input").on("change", (e)=>{
         const tgt = e.target;
         const isMain = $(tgt).hasClass("main_input");
         const isSecond = $(tgt).hasClass("second_input");
         if (isMain) events.push("main")
         if (isSecond) events.push("second")
         console.log(events)
         if (events.length === 2) {
            console.log("both have been changed")
         }
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
#1 <input type="file" class="main_input"><br/>
#2 <input type="file" class="second_input"><br/>
```

Comment: your solution seems not to work for me, the code does not give any output, somehow `$(this).hasClass("second__input");` or the other input returns false even if i can select the class in the browser developer tab

Comment: I did not notice the () => which means I need to pass the event. See update - notice I changed `second__input` to `second_input`